# How can I find StackOverflow answers in my search results easier?

Tags: search-engines, context

In my every day Google, Yahoo, and Bing searches, how can I better pick out the results that are StackOverflow results? (Sure wish my browser knew I preferred getting StackOverflow results)

Answer (score 4):

You can get augmented search results showing a StackOverflow icon to the right of the results that match using a Kynetx info card and a card selector.

[image: Augmented search results for StackOverflow answers]

The "StackOverflow fan card" can be found at

http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2009/11/the-context-of-a-stackoverflow-junkie/

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you really only care about getting SO results, you can use the site: stackoverflow.com option on your search.

example:

```
stackoverflow answers site:stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: True, but there have been many times where I have searched for something without thinking of StackOverflow and there was a StackOverflow answer.